# How to sum multi columns by regex in Polars?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

I have multi columns which name startswith "ts" like "ts_1, ts_2, ts_3,etc" , I want to sum these f64 value row by row, but I don't know exactly the column names. If I use regex like `pl.col('^ts.*$')`. How to sum these value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Update: Polars >= 0.13.60

As of Polars 0.13.60, you can now use [`polars.sum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.sum.html) with a regex argument to `polars.col`.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.sum(pl.col("^ts_.*$")).alias('ts_sum')
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ ts_1 ┆ a    ┆ ts_2 ┆ b     ┆ ts_3 ┆ ts_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 1    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 111    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 112    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 113    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 114    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

##### Other methods

There are two ways to accomplish this.  Starting with this data:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'ts_1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a': [-100] * 4,
    'ts_2': [10] * 4,
    'b': [-1000] * 4,
    'ts_3': [100] * 4,
})
df
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┐
│ ts_1 ┆ a    ┆ ts_2 ┆ b     ┆ ts_3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┘
```

As of Polars 0.13.59, you can use a regex expression in [`fold`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.fold.html).

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.fold(acc=pl.lit(0),
            f=lambda acc, x: acc + x,
            exprs=pl.col("^ts_.*$"))
    .alias("ts_sum")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ ts_1 ┆ a    ┆ ts_2 ┆ b     ┆ ts_3 ┆ ts_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 1    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 111    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 112    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 113    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 114    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

The other option is to use the fold-like properties of [`polars.sum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.sum.html).  `polars.sum` will sum horizontally when passed a **list of Expressions**.  For example:

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.sum(
        [col_nm for col_nm in df.columns
         if col_nm.startswith(r"ts_")]
    ).alias("ts_sum")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ ts_1 ┆ a    ┆ ts_2 ┆ b     ┆ ts_3 ┆ ts_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 1    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 111    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 112    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 113    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 114    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

If needed, you can use regex-type filtering, using a regex module such as `re`.

```py
import re
df.with_column(
    pl.sum(
        [col_nm for col_nm in df.columns
         if re.search(r"^ts_.*$", col_nm)]
    ).alias("ts_sum")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬────────┐
│ ts_1 ┆ a    ┆ ts_2 ┆ b     ┆ ts_3 ┆ ts_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 1    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 111    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 112    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 113    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ -100 ┆ 10   ┆ -1000 ┆ 100  ┆ 114    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Polars 0.13.60 added a new, easy way to use a regex expression in `polars.sum`.  I've update the answer to reflect this.